# How to avoid adding nodes on a line during delaunay triangulation

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, triangulation, delaunay

I am using the open source program triangle.c (A Two-Dimensional Quality Mesh Generator and Delaunay Triangulator)  which can be found [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). I have to use this program to mesh a 2d circle and then rotate it to get 3d mesh of a sphere. Once I specify the points on the boundary, the program adds additional nodes inside the region and generates triangular meshes. However I would like to avoid adding nodes on the axis about which I want to rotate. Is there a good way to achieve this?

[the 2d geometry i want to mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlNjP.png)

Comment: Do mean this:https://m.imgur.com/a/nLaZe (bottom pic)?

Comment: So you are creating a volumetric mesh or how do you plan to do the rotation? Why do you need points inside the circle and why do you need to use this program at all? There are well-established ways to triangulate a sphere.

Comment: I have to do a electromagnetic simulation of a toroidal scatterer in a spherical domain. I am planning to do this in two steps. First I do a meshing of the 2d region of a big circle inside which there are two small circles kept off center. There should not be any triangles crossing the boundary of small circles. In the second step I intend to rotate this to get a 3d mesh. However this step becomes difficult if there are vertices on the axis of rotation.

Comment: I have given added a link of the 2d geometry in my question. By rotating this about the central axis I get a toroid embedded in spherical domain.

Comment: @Betterdev  I am not able to do that kind of regular meshing because I need two sub circles inside the region. The meshing should be such that no triangles cross the boundary of the sub circles. Please check the figure I have now added at the end of the question.

Comment: You could try sloan algorithm:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075386/a-brute-force-constrained-delaunay-triangulation/42176376#comment71807287_42176376.

Comment: @Betterdev thank you. Is there a free implementation of the algorithm available?

Comment: @praveenkr:Unfortunately not. Maybe cgal.